# Actionscript memory management?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-management, garbage-collection

I saw `System.gc()` somewhere on the internet today and I wanted to know if it is or isn't recommended to use in a Flash CS5 project and why.

Comment: you should search for similar questions about Flex instead of actionscript. I'm sure you'll find existing answers on the matter (GC in Flash).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In every garbage-collected system I know of, the garbage collection machinery was designed to run in the background as an abstraction the programmer should theoretically pay no attention to. There are some special situations where forcing a collection is useful, but these usually involve interrupts (real machine interrupts, not actionscript events), testing/debugging scenarios, or some tricky latency management necessities. Odds are you will never need to call System.gc() and you can safely ignore it.

Comment: Plus, afaik, it isn't possible to force gc on release build, it's all automated and all you can do is remove all not needed listeners and stuff of this kind.

Answer (score 0):

System.gc() is only available in the debugger version of Flash Player and some AIR applications. Calling it on a normal website, under a normal Flash Player will have no effect whatsoever and will silently fail.

System.gc() is designed only for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

System.gc() is only for testing purposes.  It can be handy to monitor the memory usage your application is using and call System.gc() in order to highlight the possibility of any memory leaks.

Tip: As far as I remember you have to call System.gc() twice to force it to collect immediately.

The documentation states that this method only works in a debug player.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#gc()

So, to summarise, if you're testing memory, it's quite handy, otherwise don't use it.